# How to hide all tabs on default with jQuery accordion?

Tags: jquery

I have implement Jquery accordian in my wesbite as shown [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible). I have enabled collapsible which allows me to collapse all tabs. But I'd like all tabs to be closed by default. Currently the first tab is open by default. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the `active` option to `false`.

> Boolean: Setting active to false will collapse all panels. This requires the collapsible option to be true.

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/